# IBM DB2 SQL sleep, wait or delay for stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, delay, db2-400, timedelay

I have a small loop procedure that is waiting for another process to write a flag to a table. Is there any way to add a delay so this process doesn't consume so much cpu? I believe it may need to run between 1-2 min if everything ends correctly.

```
BEGIN

DECLARE STOPPED_TOMCAT VARCHAR (1);

UPDATE MRC_MAIN.DAYEND SET DENDSTR = 'Y';
SET STOPPED_TOMCAT = (SELECT TOMCSTP FROM MRC_MAIN.DAYEND);
WHILE ( STOPPED_TOMCAT <> 'Y')
    DO
       SET STOPPED_TOMCAT = (SELECT TOMCSTP FROM MRC_MAIN.DAYEND);
END WHILE;
END;
```

Comment: Use a cron, and call the periodically procedure from the OS?

Comment: Not sure this would work. This will need to be called at the begining of a set of procedures. Basically I will write a flag and kick off another process on a windows server once this process is done it will write back to this table and this SQL loop can now end. This will trigger the rest of the procedures to continue.

Answer (score 2):

Use `call dbms_alert.sleep(x)`, where x - number of seconds.

Comment: Doesn't seem like we have that module. 
[Code: -204, SQL State: 42704]  [SQL0204] SLEEP in DBMS_ALERT type *N not found.

Comment: You should tag your question properly - with `[db2-400]` tag, if it's Db2 for IBM i system, where such a routine really doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the resources to test this solution, but why don't try calling IBM i Command DLYJOB in your code:

```
CALL QCMDEXC('DLYJOB DLY(1)', 13);
```

The parameter DLY indicates the wait time in seconds and the number 13 is the length of the command string being executed.

Comment: Where would you suggest I call this? In the loop or outside? And should this be called before or after any specific command?